# Flutter adding video controller and player into container

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, background

I'am trying solve this issue but seems like nobody has a clue want use videoplayer background instead of an image, if someone can help i will be grateful

I have this code that create no error outside the container but once inside i got errors

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

    VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      _controller.play();
      _controller.setLooping(true);
      // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized
    
    });
```

want insert it into my container to make video background working in my app instead image Bg

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  static const your_client_id = '000000000000';
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  static const your_redirect_url =
      'https://xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler';

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
    image: AssetImage("asset/images/bg.jpg"),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )
    ),
```

Comment: Where you are adding video and what is the error ?

Comment: In Container replacing the image background